# convert list of strings to list of java type objects in clojure

Tags: mongodb, clojure, clojurescript, clojure-java-interop

I am using mongo java driver along with clojure for mongo connection, to establish connection in java I am using following code snippet

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;

MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://xxx:***@url:27017/test?readPreference=primary");
List<String> hosts = uri.getHosts();
List<ServerAddress> serverList = new LinkedList<>();

for(String host:hosts) {
    serverList.add(new ServerAddress(host)); //updated
}
```

I want to get this same functionality in clojure so I tried this

```
(def uri (MongoClientURI. uri))
(def hosts (.getHosts uri))
```

Now I have List of hosts which are String, how do I convert them to list of type ServerAddress ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's perhaps a little hard to spot in the Java code is that because `serverList` is a `List<ServerAddress>`, when you add `String` objects to that, they are implicitly converted to `ServerAddress` objects via the latter's constructor.

Something like the following should get you what you want:

```
(def host (map #(ServerAddress. %) (.getHosts uri)))
```

Note that you'll have a Clojure sequence at that point -- if you are passing it into Java methods, you may need to type hint it or even pour it into a (mutable) Java `List`.

Comment: No, the Java code is just wrong. It does not implicitly do any conversion, it just fails to compile.

Comment: There wasn't enough information in the OP's post for me to easily try out the Java code (what dependencies? what versions?) and the OP accepted my answer so... _shrug_

Comment: Sure, your answer is totally right, they just need a specific way to convert a String to a Foo. It's just that Java never does any implicit conversions except for upcasts, and ServerAddress is clearly not a supertype of String, so we can easily tell that the Java code also doesn't compile.